# Bootstrap - span div's aligning vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I've been trying to align the span3 `<div>` next to each other but I keep getting them one above the other.

So, I want to have:

SPAN3  SPAN3

and instead I am getting:

SPAN3

SPAN3

I appreciate any help here, thank you very much!

```
<div class="container">



        <div class="row-fluid" >

            <div class="span3">

                <form class="well" action="login.php">
                <legend>Sign In</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        </br><input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" class="input-large"></br></br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        </br><input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" class="input-large"></br></br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button></br></br>
                        <a> OR </a></br></br>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">New user? Register Here!</button>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

            <div class="span3">

                <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="sijpg">

            </div>

        </div>



    </div>
```

Comment: seems fine... can you post a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: Here is the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7126/

For some reason it didnt work with external css so i just copy-pasted my entire bootstrap.min.css .

I am using bootstrap 3.0

Comment: bootstrap 3.0 no longer uses the "span3" class (or any of the other numbers) which is why it's not working for you. You're using bootstrap 2.x HTML, but 3.x CSS.  As Ivan noted below, use the latest CSS from version 2 (bootstrap 2.3.2), and everything should work for you.  example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VtjQa/ (also, since this is designed to be responsive, make sure you stretch the "results" view window to full width, otherwise the media query will kick in and the second span3 will wrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, the issue is in Bootstrap 3.0 - It has some bugs in its bootstrap.min.css file.

My suggestion - download 2.3.2, it will work just fine

Comment: this is effectively the correct answer with the aside that there are not bugs in 3.0 - it is simply a large scale change from 2.x and span classes are no longer used.  for a full list of major class changes, see: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

Answer (score 0):

```
.span3 { display:inline-block; }
```

That is?

Comment: That does make them stack one next to each other, but now they are not inline, the second SPAN3 is a bit lower than the first one.

By my humble understanding of bootstrap, they should be perfectly aligned?
Also, if I try to do class="span3 offset2", or any other offset for that matter -> nothing will happen, as if its not even in the css.

Comment: Are you talking to me? You can fix that with the padding property of the first span3 form.

Comment: I understand you can fix the small offset by using paddings and margins, but that is not the point here. Given the cleanness and simplicity of bootstrap I was hoping to get an answer which wouldn't require of me to add additional (unnecessary) CSS properties.